# How do I make multiple passwords for a password protected webpage html js?

Tags: javascript, html, string, passwords, password-protection

I tried making multiple passwords for a project, but every time I did it it would always prompt me back

```js
var password;
var pass = "pass1", "pass2", "pass3";
access = prompt('Password Key', '');
if (access == pass)
  alert('Password Valid');
else {
  window.location.href = "passwordcorrect.html";
}
```

Comment: passwords in the javascript that is loaded in the browser provides no "protection" value whatsoever - anyway, check your browser console for errors - that code won't prompt for a password

Comment: Im gonna obfuscate the script so it would protect the passwords.

Comment: That doesn't really work. The user can directly navigate to `passwordcorrect.html` anyway.

Comment: See [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) at MDN.

Comment: obfuscation provides no protection

Comment: @showdev - OP's code has no array, it has an invalid line `var pass = "pass1", "pass2", "pass3";` which will prevent the script from even running

Comment: To clarify, I'm suggesting the use of an array in this context. I also agree that best practice would be not to store passwords in client-side code.

Comment: wait no, "passwordcorrect.html" is not the actual name, its just login or something, if the key is validated then it will show the actual page and then if its incorrect it will hyperlink to "passwordcorrect.html", "passwordcorrect.html" has the alerts and prompts so it will be impossible to view it except for viewing page src

Answer (score -1):

As others have mentioned, I also recommend against storing sensitive data like passwords in client-side code for any public project. However, doing so may be sufficient for your purposes.

In your context, I suggest storing the passwords in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to determine whether the array includes the input value.

```js
const keychain = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3"];
const inputkey = prompt('Password Key', '');

if (keychain.includes(inputkey)) {
  alert('Valid');
} else {
  alert('Invalid');
}
```